# GET request returns single ID information

Tags: api, express, bigcommerce

I have the following API call that is supposed to return data for each of the IDs, however for v2, instead of returning information about each order, it only displays one of the IDs. The funny thing is all orders get displayed in the console log.

```
 app.get("/all", function (req, res) {
        api.get("/v3/orders/refunds")

            .then((response) => {
                // console.log(response.data[0].order_id) 
                // console.log(response)

                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    // console.log(response.data[i].order_id)
                    let ids = response.data[i].order_id;
                    // console.log(ids)

                    api.get(`/v2/orders/${ids}`)
                        .then((refundedOrders) => {

                            bothResponses = {
                                v3: response,
                                v2: refundedOrders
                            }

                            console.log(bothResponses)
                            res.status(200).json(bothResponses)
                        })
                    }
            })

            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a `for` loop to loop through the various orders, but inside that `for` loop, you call:

```
 res.status(200).json(bothResponses)
```

You only get one response per request so when you call that on the first iteration of the `for` loop, no other responses will be sent for that request again.  Subsequent calls to `res.json()` in that `for` loop will be ignored.  In fact, they should have been outputting a warning to your console about "headers already sent" or something like that.

Instead, you need to accumulate the results for all the ids into an array and then send one response with all the data in it.

You could use `Promise.all()` to accumulate all the orders into an array and notify you when it's done like this:

```
app.get("/all", function(req, res) {
    api.get("/v3/orders/refunds").then((response) => {
        // console.log(response.data[0].order_id) 
        // console.log(response)

        return Promise.all(response.data.map(item => {
            return api.get(`/v2/orders/${item.order_id}`);            
        })).then(refundedOrders => {
            let bothResponses = {
                v3: response,
                v2: refundedOrders
            }

            console.log(bothResponses);
            res.json(bothResponses);
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStaus(500);
    })
});
```

**List of improvements:**

1. Use `.map()` to iterate the array.  Return a promise for each item in the array.
2. Use `Promise.all()` to monitor the array of promises and turn it into an array of ordered results.
3. Create one response to the http request and send that one response when all the data is available.
4. Send error status when there's an error in any of the api calls.
5. Remove `.status(200)` as that is already the default so it is unnecessary.
6. Add error handling for 2nd API call (by returning promise to the higher level so the `.catch()` will catch those 2nd API call errors too).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'll definitely improve my future API work. Unfortunately, the result is still the same - v2 displays only one of the orders and console logs both of them.

Comment: @SamuilIlkov - I can't help you debug code I can't see.  If you want help with other iterations of the code, you will have to "edit" your question to add the new iterations to the end of the answer and leave me a comment telling me you've done so.  Don't change the previous iterations in your question (since they represent the original question).

Comment: UPDATE: Added an array outside of the API call and pushed "refundedOrders". Than v2 is v2: dataArray[0] and seems to work good. Thank you for your help!